# Cordova not available when testing through ionic "devApp"?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am testing my app with ionic "DevAPP" where you can test your app live together with native support: https://ionicframework.com/docs/appflow/devapp/.

However, I am still getting cordova_not_available error on the real device , I have cordova platforms added as well as you can see my ionic info below in the screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wL03y.png)

(Please Note: I am running the app through DevAPP not directly running the app on my android device).

Any idea why it's still showing cordova_not_available?

Comment: Hi, did you check that your plugin is supported in DevApp?  Also are you using Ionic v4 as it looks like DevApp support is a bit sketchy?

Answer (score 0):

Cordova services are not available in browser if you are running application with

```
ionic serve
```

You have to use plugin to simulate cordova. You can always deploy app to android and ios without this error.

Comment: I don't think that's true for 'DevApp'.  The point of it is to allow Cordova plugin access whilst using ionic serve, though it suggests using 'ionic serve -c' or  'ionic serve --devapp'

Comment: yes @daddywoodland is right, isn't that the point of the "DEV APP" so it can make use of the device's features through cordova